# How do I build an editable menu in ASP.NET and VB

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, menu

I am working on building a CMS, my client's specific request was that he should be able to modify/edit the nav menu and its contents using the user interface, I am not sure how to do it.

Can someone please help by providing links to articles where I can learn? or even examples that I can implement?

Site2you.com has a template that can be edited pretty easily but I am not sure how they did it

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table with fields like Link Name, Link URL, Link order, and isLinkActive.

That way you can create an interface to allow the client to edit these menu items and save changes to the DB.

To display the stuff, just bind it to a Repeater.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) for some info about using Repeaters if you're not familiar with the control yet. The rest is Database design I guess.